# Tag missing from API Gateway when using tags in serverless

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless

I put tag information in tags in provider of `serverless.yml`. After executing `sls deploy`, I checked lambda from console of AWS, tag setting was done. However, when we confirmed the `apigateway` from AWS' console, the tag information was empty.

How can I tag information to the API gateway resource?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tags for API Gateway arrived after serverless' core functionality was developed.

There is an [open issue on Github](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/4644) discussing the inclusion of this functionality.

Right now you'll have to use the [serverless-tag-api-gateway](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-tag-api-gateway) plugin to manually add tags to these resources.

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much!